# AngularJS Karma Jasmine Testing Directive Fails because of $compile?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm writing a test using Jasmine for a directive in angularJS.  In karma.conf.js i've included all the dependencies and the path to my modules.  The directive i'm working with is quite complex so I borrowed some simple custom directive code for testing purposes.  It works great in js fiddle and the directive functions in my application, but it fails the test below in my application:

My spec looks something like this:

```
describe('Unit testing: ', function() {
  var $compile,
      $rootScope;

 beforeEach(module('app.directives'));  // our directives

  // Store references to $rootScope and $compile
  // so they are available to all tests in this describe block
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_){
    // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  }));

  it('Replaces the element with the appropriate content', function() {
    // Compile a piece of HTML containing the directive
    var element = $compile("<div hello-world></div>")($rootScope);

    // fire all the watches, so the scope expression {{1 + 1}} will be evaluated
    $rootScope.$digest();

    // Check that the compiled element contains the templated content
    expect(element.html()).toContain("Hello World!");
  });
});
```

The directive looks like this:

```
angular.module('app.directives')
.directive('helloWorld', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      template: '<h3>Hello World!!</h3>'
  };
});
```

When I run grunt karma the last test fails because:

```
Firefox 40.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.10.0) Unit testing:  Replaces the element with the appropriate content FAILED
    Expected '' to contain 'Hello World!'.
```

The major problem that I see when I insert some console.log statements is that the directive isn't compiling correctly after I call $compile (or after $digest for that matter):

```
Firefox 40.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.10.0) LOG: {0: <div class="ng-scope" hello-world=""></div>, length: 1}
```

I'm pretty stumped.  I know I might need to supply some more info about my application, but this explanation is my core issue in a nutshell.

[edit]: creating a new module is a quick fix to this, but the question still remains as to how to deal with directive unit testing when there are multiple directives in a single module (which still fails).

Comment: Your directive's name is *"mmsHelloWorld"* so shouldn't your template look like `<div mms-hello-world></div>`? Ie, you're missing the `mms-` prefix

Comment: mms is just a naming convention specific to the application i'm working on.  I was trying to generalize the code and make it more intutive so I removed it, but obviously not all of them!  Sorry!

Comment: Your directive name should be *"helloWorld"*, not *"HelloWorld"* though I'm not entirely sure if the leading capital letter makes a difference but better safe than sorry :)

Comment: You are right, but that was a part of the edits to the naming convention too.  I should be paying more attention before I post code :(.

Comment: Ah, it's `replace: 'false'`. The `'false'` string is evaluating to `true`. Either set `replace: false` or just omit `replace` entirely (it's deprecated anyway)

Comment: Working here without `replace` ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/fTufgqL7Vun9T9W7FtwY?p=preview

Comment: Another good suggestion (and good to know), but I have the same error.

Comment: You're right; the Plunker example works with `replace: true` as well

Comment: I think it might be a issue with the karma.conf.js file, but it's picking up the module (ie there's no error that the module doesn't exist) and I've done similar testing with the services with no issues (though directive testing is totally different)

Comment: Only thing I'd recommend it creating a separate module for each directive. At the minimum, it allows you to test them in isolation which is what unit testing is all about.

Comment: The way the directives are called as a single module is essential to the application right now.  However, you're right they do need to be broken down into separate modules.  I'm going to create a test module and see if this fixes the issue.  i'll get back to you soon.

Comment: You can still create your `app.directives` module and have it include each module, eg `angular.module('app.directives', ['app.directives.hello-world', 'app.directives.something-else,...])`

Comment: Creating its own module fixes this issue for this singular test.  However, the application still runs by using html2js and lumping the directives in the build file into a single js file of html templates (so the issue isn't a preproccessor).  I guess the question now is can I still test directives with this implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answer edited)
Your code worked for me once I made sure it was included in my karma.conf.js properly.

```
files: [
    "include/path/to/your/directive/file.js",
    "include/path/to/your/directive/test.js"
]
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but the inner html is still empty.  I tried the angular.element method as well.

Comment: So this issue was related to the karma config file as suggested.  The order of the files, it's dependencies and the build directory had to be refactored in order for this to work.